# How can I match multiple occurences with my regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
(?s)Table.*?Seat (\\d).*?\\((\\d+).*?HOLE
```

and following file structure:

```
Table xxx123
Seat 1: xxx (1537 xxx)
Seat 3: yyy (609 yyy)
Seat 5: zzz (485 zzz)
xxx123 HOLE
```

At the moment I get just the 1 and 1537 as a match. I tried different changes to my regex and searched for solutions in different threads, but it looks like I am not able to solve this.

I thought that the following modification should work, but it doesn't:

```
(?s)Table.*?(Seat (\\d).*?\\((\\d+).*?).*?HOLE
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? what do you want to match exactly? which programming language do you want to use for that purpose?

Comment: I also want to match the numbers 3, 609, 5 and 485. Programming language is Java.

Comment: Do you need to ensure that the lines with the numbers are enclosed between `Table...` and `...HOLE`? In other words, would something like [`Seat (\d).*?\((\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Eg0vFR/1) not be sufficient?

Comment: I can get the specific part as a substring if there is really no other way. But I would prefer to solve this with a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The pattern you're looking for is [`\G`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds):

> The end of the previous match

This is then used with a [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) loop. On the first call to `find()`, `\G` matches the beginning of input. On subsequent calls, it matches the end of the previous match.

To prevent it from matching the beginning of input, you use a [zero-width negative look-behind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), then combine that with a [`|` OR operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical) to match the `Table` text at the beginning of input, and surround that with a [non-capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special).

```
(?:           start non-capturing group
   (?!<^)         not at beginning of input
   \G             match end of previous match
  |             OR
   Table          match "Table"
)             end non-capturing group
```

You then look for and match what you want to capture.

```
.*?Seat (\d).*?\((\d+)
```

Now, you don't want to actually match the trailer (`.*?HOLE`), because that would prevent `\G` from continuing on the next `find()` iteration. Instead, you just ensure that it's there using a [zero-width positive look-ahead](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special).

```
(?=.*?HOLE)
```

*Demo*

```
String input = "Table xxx123\n" +
               "Seat 1: xxx (1537 xxx)\n" +
               "Seat 3: yyy (609 yyy)\n" +
               "Seat 5: zzz (485 zzz)\n" +
               "xxx123 HOLE";

String regex = "(?s)(?:(?<!^)\\G|Table).*?Seat (\\d).*?\\((\\d+)(?=.*?HOLE)";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
```

*Output*

```
1 1537
3 609
5 485
```

Note that this is not the best solution, because it'll keep scanning for the trailer for every match found.